# How to redirect after login with grail-spring security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am new to grail and dont know how to redirect after ajax login success. Can anyone please put step by step process.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give any other details or relevant code excerpts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, the `spring-security-core` plugin doesn't have UI logic for doing AJAX logins.  I'm going to assume you're using the `spring-security-ui` plugin as well.

If you've run `s2-quickstart`, you'll have a `LoginController` in `grails-app/controllers`.  The `ajaxSuccess` action gets called when an AJAX login succeeds.  The default implementation looks like this:

```
def ajaxSuccess = {
    render([success: true, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name]
           as JSON)
}
```

If you look closely at the `spring-security-ui` AJAX login support in `ajaxLogin.js`, you'll see that the JSON response can include an URL value for redirection.  The default implementation doesn't provide one, but it's easy add.  Just update `ajaxSuccess` to look something like this:

```
def ajaxSuccess = {
    render([success: true, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name,
            url: '/defaultLoginPage'] as JSON)
}
```